# most elegant way to remove string element

Tags: c#, string

I'm fetching string from output file which will always be either `Ok` or `Err`.
After that I'm casting this result `Ok` or `Err` to Enum property, which is ok, everything works, but I'm sure that there must be a better way than mine.

Since I'm fetching 3 characters in case that `Ok` is fetched I need to remove third element from `Ok`; result.

```
string message = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\SomeReport.txt").Substring(411, 3);
 if (message == "Ok;") // `;` character should be removed in case that Ok is fetched
 {
    message = "Ok";
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: If you expect the precise position 411 for the string, you could check only for `Ok`: `File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\SomeReport.txt").Substring(411, 2);`. If the message is anything else but `Ok`, then probably it's an error. Makes sense?

Comment: I'm expecting either Ok or Err result. That's way I use Substring(411, 3);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `String.Trim()` to remove the ';' if its there.

```
string message = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\SomeReport.txt").Substring(411, 3).TrimEnd(';')
```

Result:

```
"Err" = "Err"
"Ok;" = "Ok"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
switch (message)
{
  case "Err":
    SomeProperty = EnumName.Err;
    break;

  case "Ok;":
    SomeProperty = EnumName.Ok;
    break;

  default:
    throw new Exception("Unexpected file contents: " + message);
}
```

If you don't like that, you can use `TryParse` after trimming the semicolon:

```
EnumName result;
if (Enum.TryParse(message.TrimEnd(';'), out result))
  SomePropery = result;
else
  throw new Exception("Unexpected file contents: " + message);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     Enum message = Enum.Err;
     if (Regex.Match(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\SomeReport.txt"), "(ok.+?){3}", RegexOptions.Singleline).Success)
     {
        message = Enum.OK;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the following enum

```
public enum State
{
    Err, OK
}
```

using trimming, as sa_adam213 said you can convert it to your enum this way:

```
string message = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\SomeReport.txt").Substring(411, 3).TrimEnd(';')
State state = (State)Enum.Parse(typeof(State),message);
MessageBox.Show(state.ToString());  //should show OK or Err
```

and also cast it to int:

```
int i = (int)state;
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());  //should show 1 or 0
```